# Empty rows insertion in Many-to-One and Many-to-Many relationships in GraphDiff

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, graphdiff

I am using GraphDiff, along with the latest version of the Entity Framework, following the code-first approach.

I am trying to update a `Food` entity this way:

```
public void Update(Food food)
{
    using (var db = new DatabaseMappingContext())
    {
        food = db.UpdateGraph(food, map => map.OwnedEntity(f => f.FoodRecipe, withRecipe => withRecipe.
               OwnedCollection(r => r.RecipeSteps, withRecipeStep => withRecipeStep.
                   OwnedCollection(rs => rs.StartObjectSlots, withStartObjectSlots => withStartObjectSlots.
                       AssociatedEntity(sos => sos.BelongingRecipeStepAsStart)
                   ).
                   OwnedCollection(rs => rs.EndObjectSlots, withEndObjectSlots => withEndObjectSlots.
                       AssociatedEntity(eos => eos.BelongingRecipeStepAsEnd)
                   ).
                   AssociatedEntity(rs => rs.ActionOfUser)
               ).
               AssociatedCollection(r => r.InteractiveObjects)
            ).
            AssociatedCollection(f => f.FoodVarieties));
        //....
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`StartObjectSlots` and `EndObjectSlots` are 2 lists containing some other, irrelevant data.
The `InteractiveObjects` contains objects of a `InteractiveObject` type, which is the base type for a number of object types that can be put there. One of those derived types (let's say `IntObjDerived` has a One-to-Many property).
Now, I am trying to update the following entity this way:

```
ServerAdapter sa = new ServerAdapter();
//Loading a food from DB.
Food food = sa.LoadAllFoods().First();
RecipeStep rs = new RecipeStep();
rs.Name = "This is a test recipe step";
//Adding a User Action from the database.
rs.ActionOfUser = sa.LoadAllUserActions().First();
//....
//Add the step in the recipe
food.FoodRecipe.RecipeSteps.Add(rs);
//Update the food.
sa.Update(food);
```

Now, when the code is executed, a new empty ActionOfUser entity is inserted into the database. Additionally, <del>a new empty entity is inserted for each of the one-to-many navigation properties of the entities mentioned above</del> three new recipes are inserted in the database, one of empty data, one half filled and this one supposed to be saved. Both situations are unwanted, and I am trying to find the solution. I experimented with some changes, but I have stuck with this. Any suggestions?
(I know that this seems to be 2 questions, but I thought to put it as one as it might be relevant-same problem in database).

EDIT: I downloaded and compiled `GraphDiff` in order to inspect what is going on, and I noticed the creation of some objects that are empty except from their Entity ID value.
I guess that those side effects are caused because practically I **add** a new node to the object graph (a new RecipeStep) and I am not sure if graphdiff fully supports this.

UPDATE (`tl; dr` version): I tried to apply a `UpdateGraph` call using Entity Framework's GraphDiff of an object with graph depth greater than 2.
By what I have tried, it seems that GraphDiff is applying double insertions in graphs of depth greater than 2 and it takes a lots of time, especially if a new node is added with subnodes loaded from the database. Should I follow a different approach, for example split the `UpdateGraph` call into multiple calls?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Definitely you need to explain a little bit about your issue. Is very hard to read. Can you simplify the problem?

Comment: Added simplified version of the question.

Comment: Can you please copy your current model?

Comment: I am afraid that this is not possible. I posted an answer though on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally applied as a workaround, was to perform the update operation by splitting it into multiple `UpdateGraph` calls with graph depth less than or equal to 2 and apply manually any sub-node addition to the graph:

```
//Update food in total graph depth <= 2.
db.UpdateGraph(food, map => map.AssociatedCollection(f => f.FoodVarieties));

//.... (Other UpdateGraph calls with graph depth <=2)

//Update recipe steps of recipe in total graph depth <= 2.
foreach (RecipeStep recipeStep in food.FoodRecipe.RecipeSteps)
{
    recipeStep.ActionOfUser = db.UserActions.FirstOrDefault(ua => ua.EntityID == recipeStep.ActionOfUser.EntityID);

    //If you have to do an inner node adding operation in the graph, do it manually.
    if (recipeStep.EntityID == 0)
    {
        recipeStep.BelongingRecipe = db.Recipes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.EntityID == food.FoodRecipe.EntityID);
        db.RecipeSteps.Add(recipeStep);
    }
    else
    {
        //Map slots & recipeSteps applied manually here.
        recipeStep.StartObjectSlots.ForEach(sos => sos.BelongingRecipeStepAsStart = recipeStep);
        recipeStep.EndObjectSlots.ForEach(eos => eos.BelongingRecipeStepAsEnd = recipeStep);

        db.UpdateGraph(recipeStep, map => map.OwnedCollection(rs => rs.InteractiveObjectInstancesLists, withIOILists => withIOILists.
                OwnedCollection(ioil => ioil.InteractiveObjectsInstances)
            ).
            OwnedCollection(rs => rs.StartObjectSlots, withStartObjectSlots => withStartObjectSlots.
                AssociatedEntity(sos => sos.BelongingRecipeStepAsStart)
            ).
            OwnedCollection(rs => rs.EndObjectSlots, withEndObjectSlots => withEndObjectSlots.
                AssociatedEntity(eos => eos.BelongingRecipeStepAsEnd)
            ).
            AssociatedEntity(rs => rs.ActionOfUser)
        );

    }
}
```

Also, I noticed that the object's graph update was completed much faster than before. These might be indications of *something going wrong* in `GraphDiff` complex graph (>2 depth) updating process (or at least I was doing something terribly wrong).